# regex that allows chinese characters

Tags: java, xml, regex, character

I have a regex that blocks invalid characters in a string, but it's also blocking chinese characters and i dont want it.  Please help me with it. Below is the regex string that I am using.

```
String re = "[^\\x09\\x0A\\x0D\\x20-\\xD7FF\\xE000-\\xFFFD\\x10000-x10FFFF]";
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: instead of blocking char's you can match the allowed chars..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Java 7 you can make use of [Unicode properties/scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

E.g. you can use the property `\p{L}` to match a letter in any language. Or the script `\p{IsHiragana}` to match a character contained in Hiragana. You need to check what script is fitting your needs.

See here on [docs.Oracle.com for more details about regex and Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html)

It is also possible to match for the opposite, e.g. `\P{L}` is matching every character, that is **NOT** a letter, or you just add `\p{L}` to your negated character class, instead of the ranges that should define letters.

Comment: @akshat - make your life easier and download Java 7 as suggested - go to oracle.com ;-)

Comment: I haven't suggested to download Java 7 (There is no Version mentioned in the original question). But before Java 7, regex on Unicode strings was a pain. I would not have a solution then.

Comment: there are certain systems that run on java 5 and cannot be enhanced. Thanks